# What is breathing Kagome lattice?

Tags: condensed-matter, lattice-model, spin-models

I know what kagome lattice is. While reading some article I came to know the term breathing kagome lattice. Looked up the web didn't found any definitions of it.

My suspicion is that when hopping parameters of the upper and lower triangles are different then the aforementioned lattice is called a breathing one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "breathing kagome lattice" refers to a kagome Heisenberg model with a "breathing" anisotropy, where the Heisenberg interaction strength on inequivalent (up-/down-triangles) is different, see e.g. Eq. (1) in https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.10105.